# Sorting categories in Magento according to the position in admin

Tags: magento

I would like to know how to sort this list of categories (I followed this tutorial here http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-category-listing-block/) in magento by position in the admin panel? Currently it is sorted by id

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($catIds as $catId): ?>
    <li>
        <?php
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
            echo '<a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">';
            echo $category->getName() . '</a>';
        ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 22):

You're making way too much work for yourself trying to deal with IDs and stuff. The following is already sorted by position as standard.

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is working like a charm. You saved my day. And yes, this is way cleaner approach than using cat ids and stuff. Thanks again ;)

Comment: This looks good, but I don't seem to be able to get a working version. Using magento 1.6.  I'd like to load up categories for the active store.

Comment: @Lucas - To modify this snippet replace the category ID (in this case `3`) with `Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()`. However there are other ways too, look at the `catalog/navigation/*.phtml` templates to see how it is normally done, or open a new question if you need something specific.

Comment: Brilliant! I also added the condition `if($subCategory->getIsActive()) {` inside the loop.

Comment: This is very concise, how would you get access to other attributes like the product description? Does not seem to be available this way.

Comment: @johnsnails Here, `$cats` is already loaded so cannot be modified further and only includes "url", "name", "position", "is_anchor", "is_active" fields.  To see the description as well you must use one of the other answers that allows you to call `addAttributeToSelect()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sort the categories by the position created in adminhtml you can then, since `catalog/category` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection`, make a query where you specify what you want to select, filter and/or sort.

The case here is getting categories from `catalog_category_entity` select only the name, filtering after the id and **sort** the query on the `position`.

```
<?php 
 $subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $categoryId)
->addAttributeToSort('position', ASC);
?>
```

Comment: Why is this a solution? Please explain.

Comment: This works if you use `'position'` instead of `'name'`.

Comment: This answer also expects you to be iterating through parent categories. For top level categories you can use: `->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)` without the `->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $categoryId)` line. The level is 2 for top level categories since they are under the root category, which is level 1.

Answer (score 3):

**This is what I did:**

```
$allCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$CategoriesTree = $allCategories->getTreeModel()->load();
$categoriesIds = 
$CategoriesTree->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')->getAllIds();
```

**after to retrieve the categories:**

```
$categoryChildren = array();    

if ($categoriesIds) {
    foreach ($categoriesIds as $categoryId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $categoryChildren[] = $category;
    }
}
```

**and then:**

```
// Sort by position
function comparePosition($a, $b) {
    if ($a->position == $b->position)
        return 0;
        return ($a->position > $b->position) ? 1 : -1;
    }

usort($categoryChildren, 'comparePosition');
```

Inverting the return (1 and -1) would obviously change the order.
It worked just fine for me.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to lok here first http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections and also other articles in knowledge base are a must read for any magento dev.

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->addAttributeToSort('yourfield', 'desc')->getCollection()->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
?>
```

Comment: really helpful comment :) what field name did you use for sorting

Comment: $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'desc')->load(3)->getChildren();

Comment: @Anton - That could never work because a model is a model, not a collection. Only collections can be sorted.

Comment: you are right i forgot the collection part that can be easily used instead of load

Comment: Hmm, still not working. MAybe the admin parameters for position are stored somewhere else.

Comment: And shouldn't be addAttributeToSort at the end?

Comment: use the clockworkgeek approach my suggestions are theoretical and never tested

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $model_category =   Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getEntityId());
    $sub_categories     =   $model_category->getCollection();
    $sub_categories     ->  addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                        ->  addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->  addAttributeToFilter('is_active',1)
                        ->  addIdFilter($model_category->getChildren())
                        ->  setOrder('position', 'ASC')
                        ->  load();
    ?>
    <?php   foreach($sub_categories->getData()  as  $each_subcat):  ?>
        <?php   $model_subcat   =   Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($each_subcat['entity_id']);    ?>                              
    <?php   endforeach; ?>
```