# How do i sort magento subcategory according to its position

Tags: magento

I have read this post to display categories sorted by position in admin. I find it helpful.

[Sorting categories in Magento according to the position in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585986/sorting-categories-in-magento-according-to-the-position-in-admin).

I followed clockworkgeek suggestion.

Now, anyone knows on how do i sort my subcategories too? I need my subcategories to be sorted according to its position. So if subcategory 1 position is 3, subcategory 2 position is 2, subcategory 3 postion is 1. The order of the subcategory name now is:

- Subcategory 3
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 1

I know in admin, by drag and drop you can change the subcategory position. I want to adopt the position changes too in the front side.

Comment: Found a solution in magento wiki. :D

For anyone looking for an answer to this issue too, please visit this page

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/getting_and_using_categories_and_subcategories

Hope that helps.

Comment: StackOverflow likes it's questions & answers to be self-contained. Can you please explain what you did as an answer below and mark it as accepted for future visitors?

Comment: I tried the code written in the wiki and I found the main categories and its subcategories listed according to its position in admin.